# jQuery: Using "insertAfter()" based on window size / Get last "data-target" value

Tags: jquery

I would like to use a two column layout. On the left side, there should be an accordion-like function. If the window size is larger than 400px, the displayed image(s) should be on the right side of the layout.

My attempt generally works. But I would need to write a jQuery function for every single "Click me" button (there should be much more in the end). Is it possible to simplify that?

An idea would be to take something like `".content-image.*get-the-last-data-target-value*"` and `".content-text.*get-the-last-data-target-value*"` instead of `".content-image.one"` and `".content-text.one"`. But I have no idea how to code it.

The code:

```js
$(".headline").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".content-text, .content-image").not(target).hide();
  target.toggle();
})


window.onresize = Resize;
window.onload = Resize;

function Resize() {
  let mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)");
  if (mq.matches) {
    $(".content-image.one").insertAfter(".content-text.one");
  } else {
    $(".content-image.one").insertAfter("#trigger");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
}

.headline {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-text,
.content-image {
  display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    display: block;
  }
  #left,
  #right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">

  <div class="headline" data-target=".one">Click me</div>
  <div class="content-text one">Here it works. The image is on the right side, if the window is wider than 400px.</div>
  <img class="content-image one" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Red_and_blue_pill.jpg">

  <div class="headline" data-target=".two">Click me</div>
  <div class="content-text two">Here it doesn't work. It would be necessary to write a jQuery function for every single "Click me" button.</div>
  <img class="content-image two" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS43e0DEbwzHSBhfegG-NZLu7idICKlf5L69A&usqp=CAU">
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div id="trigger"></div>
</div>
```

Under a window width of `400px`, the images should be placed under their corresponding text.

I would be very thankful for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the currently visible image. If there is one, examine its class list and extract the unique value (eg `one` or `two`). Then select an element with that class and `.content-text`:

```js
$(".headline").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $(".content-text, .content-image").not(target).hide();
  target.toggle();
  Resize();
});


window.onresize = Resize;
window.onload = Resize;

function Resize() {
  const $img = $('img:visible');
  if (!$img[0]) return;
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)").matches) {
    $img.insertAfter($('.content-text.' + $img[0].className.split(' ')[0]));
  } else {
    $('img:visible').insertAfter("#trigger");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
}

.headline {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-text,
.content-image {
  display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    display: block;
  }
  #left,
  #right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">

  <div class="headline" data-target=".one">Click me</div>
  <div class="content-text one">Here it works. The image is on the right side, if the window is wider than 400px.</div>
  <img class="content-image one" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Red_and_blue_pill.jpg">

  <div class="headline" data-target=".two">Click me</div>
  <div class="content-text two">Here it doesn't work. It would be necessary to write a jQuery function for every single "Click me" button.</div>
  <img class="content-image two" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS43e0DEbwzHSBhfegG-NZLu7idICKlf5L69A&usqp=CAU">
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div id="trigger"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Now, if the window width is under 400px, all images get placed under ".content-text.one". But they should be placed under their corresponding ".content-text". Do you have an idea to do that? Would be very cool! :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! Now there is an error in the console ...

Comment: Thanks again! If my window width is now under 400px, and I click the first "Click me" link, the corresponding image appears under the second "Click me" link. But it should be under the first, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems over complicated and could be done mostly with css and an extra image element on the right side and without needing to use your `Resize()` function at all

Instead of moving the image, just update the src of the image on the right side.
Then use your media query css rules ( see *"new rules added"* comment) to determine what to show/hide.
No need for window resize event handler to modify anything this way

I also wrapped each of these repeating groups in a container which also makes it easier to isolate image associated with the headline. Toggling an active class on the container is also used for the media query display css.

No unique classes or data targets are needed with this generic approach

```js
$(".headline").click(function() {  
  $('.wrapper.active').removeClass('active')
  const $cont = $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  const src =  $cont.find('.content-image').attr('src');
  $('#right-image').attr('src', src)
}).first().click()// initialize first one on page load
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    display: block;
  }
  #left,
  #right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*******************************************/
  /* new rules added*/
  #right-image{display:none}
  .wrapper.active .content-image{ display:block}
  /*******************************************/
}






* {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 50%;
}




.headline {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-text,
.content-image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="headline" >Click me</div>
    <div class="content-text">Here it works. The image is on the right side, if the window is wider than 400px.</div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Red_and_blue_pill.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="headline">Click me</div>
    <div class="content-text">Here it doesn't work. It would be necessary to write a jQuery function for every single "Click me" button.</div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS43e0DEbwzHSBhfegG-NZLu7idICKlf5L69A&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div id="trigger">
    <h3>Trigger content</h3>
  </div>
  <img id="right-image"/> 
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, wow, that's pretty smart! But I will need more than one image in some cases. So I don't think it will work for me.

Comment: Ok, fairly easy to adapt the concept to multiple images